# Django URL 404 Not Found

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm currently following sentdex's Django web dev tutorial series and I've ran into an issue. [When I click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZB6hd.png), I'm getting this 
a 404. Highlighted is the regex I'm [using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gKD7.png). I'm pretty new to Django and URLs so I'm not too sure what the issue could be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using django's url tag to find the link.

Give the url a name in the `urls.py` file

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$', DetailView.as_view(model=Vod, template_name="Annotation/post.html"), name="AnnotationPost")
```

The anchor tag should be

```
<a href="{% url 'AnnotationPost' pk=vod.id %}">{{ vod.title }}</a>
```

Comment: So I tried that and I got another 404, but this time Django didn't even check the urls in my Annotation app.

Comment: I tried that as well, but it's still not comparing it to the one url, url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)$'

Comment: There's a % missing in the anchor. it should be a href="{% url... %} try this. the url should work with this.